# How to stub consecutive calls with callbacks in mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

When using Mockito you can stub a method call like:

```
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
    .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .thenReturn("foo");
```

But when your method returns `void` you need to stub with this format:

```
    doAnswer(new Answer() {..).when(mock). someMethod("some arg");
```

Imagine I have a  `Worker.class` like this

```
class Worker {

   void doWork(Callback callback) {
        boolean success= ...;
        if(success){
            callback.onSuccess();
        }else {
            callback.onFail();
        }
   }

}
```

You can stub the calls with this code:

```
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Callback callback= invocation.getArguments()[0];
            callback.onSuccess();
            return null;
        }
    }).when(mockWorker).doWork(any(Callback.class));
```

Now imagine I want to stub that three consecutive calls to the worker to call `onFail, onSuccess, onFail` how can I do that? Do I need to reconfigure the mock inside each `answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey found the answer. You just need to chain the calls to doAnswer like:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Callback callback= invocation.getArguments()[0];
        callback.onFail();
        return null;
    }
}).
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Callback callback= invocation.getArguments()[0];
        callback.onSuccess();
        return null;
    }
}).
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Callback callback= invocation.getArguments()[0];
        callback.onFail();
        return null;
    }
}).when(mockWorker).doWork(any(Callback.class));
```